# How to create sub domain through ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dns, subdomain, dotnetnuke

I had hosted my application in a DNS server.I want to create sub domain for my domain through asp.net(DotNet Nuke).Is it possible?

For example if my domain name is: mydomain.com

I want to create sub domains like :user1.mydomain.com,user2.mydomain.com

Comment: You definitely cannot do it in an application. I think the required configuration is on the level of IIS/server.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure the "BINDINGS" in IIS, unless you have the bindings setup for * already, then anything coming in via DNS will work in IIS.

In DNN you simply need to create Portals with a portal alias for each of the subdomains you want to use.